# How to randomize x y movements at Logitech G Hub

Tags: macros, logitech

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a macro in Logitech GHub.
I managed to program everything, but I randomly movements .
Is it possible to add random moves to this macro?

I searched in many places and didn't find anything similar to my question.

I want them to move randomly and not the same as in the script.

Thank you!

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3 then
 PressKey("lshift")
            MoveMouseTo(34650, 26299)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
Sleep(math.random(13, 30)) 
            MoveMouseTo(34650,30854)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
Sleep(math.random(13, 30)) 
            MoveMouseTo(32755,30854)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
Sleep(math.random(13, 30)) 
            MoveMouseTo(30860,30794)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
Sleep(math.random(13, 30)) 
            MoveMouseTo(30911,26360)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
Sleep(math.random(13, 30)) 
            MoveMouseTo(30911,21865)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
Sleep(math.random(13, 30))          
            MoveMouseTo(32780,21805)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
Sleep(math.random(13, 30)) 
            MoveMouseTo(34650,21926)
            PressAndReleaseMouseButton(3)
ReleaseKey("lshift")
            end               
end
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use Lua function `math.random(min_value, max_value)` to get random integer in the range specified for generating random X and Y.